# Is this a Mirror tree/Karamu?

Tags: trees

This tree started growing on its own in the backyard and I left it as tree recognition apps suggested its Persimmon during the early stages. Now, the same apps detect it to be mirror tree. So just want to see if anyone to recognize it. And if it’s just a weed, would like to remove it. Any advice will be very useful.

[image: Mirror tree?]
[image: Mirror tree1?]

Comment: Not mirror bush, the leaves of mirror bush are rounder and more shiny.